# duplicate "lo0" scopes, one of which hangs on attempts to connect()

Tags: c, ipv6

My cross-platform C program takes an IPv6 address and port number, and tries to connect to the remote server they designate.  The address may or may not have a scope suffix.

I use `getifaddrs()` and iterate through the results using a pointer `struct ifaddr * pAdapter`, ignoring the entries where `pAdapter->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_INET6`.
If the user supplied a numeric scope suffix, I only look at entries where the scope ID `(sockaddr_in6 *)(pAdapter->ifa_addr)->sin6_scope_id` matches it,  and if they supplied a non-numeric suffix, I only look at the entries where `pAdapter->ifa_name` matches it.  But if the scope suffix was empty, I simply try all of the entries in turn, and the user has to live with the first successful one whichever it is. (This iteration seems unnecessary on Windows 10—from what I can tell, winsock2 seems to actually do its own similar cascade of attempts under the hood if you leave the scope ID and flow-control fields zeroed.)

On each attempt, I take a copy of `*(sockaddr_in6 *)(pAdapter->ifa_addr)`, fill in the desired `sin6_addr` and `sin6_port`, and try to `connect()` my socket. On my Ubuntu box, this works. On Windows 10, it also works, though it's probably redundant as I mentioned. But on MacBooks running system 10.13.6 and 11.2.3, I have a problem:  for some reason there are two IPv6 interfaces both called `"lo0"`, one with scope ID 0 and one with scope ID 1, and `connect()` hangs when trying through the latter.

For example, I might be trying to connect to `fe80::dead:beef%en0` (scope ID 5) and I only supply `fe80::dead:beef`.  The `fe80::dead:beef%0` attempt fails with "No route to host" and we move on, but the `fe80::dead:beef%1` attempt hangs indefinitely and we never get as far as scope 5.

Why the duplication, why does it hang, and what should I do?   Merely adding a timeout to the attempt would make the whole thing prohibitively slow.  Is there any other way I determine that scope 1 is not a viable option, and move on?

Comment: This sounds more like an OS question than a programming question.

Comment: @barmar the unwanted behavior can be isolated to a call to `connect()` in C. The solution will necessarily involve programming. A non-programmer would not be able to help.

Comment: There can only be one loopback address (`::1`) , and it should be in the default zone, which is `0`. The loopback address should be specified without an index or only with `0`. There seems to be some configuration problem on that host that there is a loopback with a scope of `1`.